# Calling cosmos DB stored procedure in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a stored procedure in Azure Cosmos DB that will delete record from my Cosmos DB. I tried to call that stored procedure from my Azure function, but I am getting an error related to json parsing when executing the stored procedure (`client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync`). I already tried changing the partition key to "id" but I still get the same error.

Here is the error message that I got:

> "Failed to deserialize stored procedure response or convert it to type 'System.String': Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1."

Stack trace

> at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.StoredProcedureResponse`1..ctor(DocumentServiceResponse response, JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.ExecuteStoredProcedurePrivateAsync[TValue](String storedProcedureLink, RequestOptions options, IDocumentClientRetryPolicy retryPolicyInstance, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] procedureParams)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.ExecuteRetryAsync(Func`1 callbackMethod, Func`3 callShouldRetry, Func`1 inBackoffAlternateCallbackMethod, TimeSpan minBackoffForInBackoffCallback, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action`1 preRetryCallback)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ShouldRetryResult.ThrowIfDoneTrying(ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.ExecuteRetryAsync(Func`1 callbackMethod, Func`3 callShouldRetry, Func`1 inBackoffAlternateCallbackMethod, TimeSpan minBackoffForInBackoffCallback, CancellationToken cancellatio
> nToken, Action`1 preRetryCallback)\r\n   at FunctionApp2.Function1.Run(HttpRequest req, IAsyncCollector`1 documentsOut, ILogger log) in C:\Users\source\repos\FunctionApp2\FunctionApp2\Function1.cs:line 36"

Stored procedure `deleteStoreSample`:

```
function bulkDeleteProcedure() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
    var response = getContext().getResponse();
    var responseBody = {
        deleted: 0,
        continuation: true
    }; 

    query = 'SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.submittedDate > "2002-08-31"';

    // Validate input.
    if (!query) 
         throw new Error("The query is undefined or null.");

    tryQueryAndDelete();

    // Recursively runs the query w/ support for continuation  tokens.
    // Calls tryDelete(documents) as soon as the query returns documents.
    function tryQueryAndDelete(continuation) {
        var requestOptions = {continuation: continuation};

        var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, requestOptions, function (err, retrievedDocs, responseOptions) {

        if (err) 
            throw err;

        if (retrievedDocs.length > 0) {
            // Begin deleting documents as soon as documents are returned form the query results.
            // tryDelete() resumes querying after deleting; no need to page through continuation tokens.
            //  - this is to prioritize writes over reads given timeout constraints.
            tryDelete(retrievedDocs);
        } else if (responseOptions.continuation) {
            // Else if the query came back empty, but with a continuation token; repeat the query w/ the token.
            tryQueryAndDelete(responseOptions.continuation);
        } else {
            // Else if there are no more documents and no continuation token - we are finished deleting documents.
            responseBody.continuation = false;
            response.setBody(responseBody);
        }
    });

    // If we hit execution bounds - return continuation: true.
    if (!isAccepted) {
        response.setBody(responseBody);
    }
}

// Recursively deletes documents passed in as an array argument.
// Attempts to query for more on empty array.
function tryDelete(documents) {
    if (documents.length > 0) {
        // Delete the first document in the array.
        var isAccepted = collection.deleteDocument(documents[0]._self, {}, function (err, responseOptions) {
            if (err) throw err;

            responseBody.deleted++;
            documents.shift();
            // Delete the next document in the array.
            tryDelete(documents);
        });

        // If we hit execution bounds - return continuation: true.
        if (!isAccepted) {
            response.setBody(responseBody);
        }
    } else {
        // If the document array is empty, query for more documents.
        tryQueryAndDelete();
    }
}
```

Azure function:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
         [CosmosDB(
    databaseName: "dbName",
    collectionName: "collectionName",
    ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDbConnectionString")]IAsyncCollector<dynamic> documentsOut,
        ILogger log)
{
    try
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string endpoint = "https://account.documents.azure.com:443/";
        string key = "gixxxx==";

        var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), key);

        Uri uri = UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri("service-order", "ServiceOrder", "deleteStoreSample");
        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("/id") };

        var result = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>(uri, options);

        var response = result.Response;

        return new OkObjectResult(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: You shared the actual account name and key in the question. Even though I edited your question and removed it but anybody with sufficient score can view the edit history. **Please change your account key ASAP to prevent its misuse**.

Comment: The IActionResult is body of the response. Good response returns with a status of 200 OK. Bad response will normally be a 400 or 500 error.  You are getting an error because the id in the request is not valid.  The IActionResult automatically get deserialized which is causing the exception.  You will not get a valid body (IActionResult) when you get an error in the response.  So first you need to find out what the status of the response is. Put a break point on return new OkObjectResult(response); and see what is contained in the response.  You should also modify code to handle errors.

Comment: @jdweng, I am doing the POC for now and don't care much on the response. My issue is that when I call client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync, I got a json error

Comment: @ramdev - Have you tried debugging your Stored Procedure? I think you can do it in Azure Portal (in Query Explorer or Data Explorer I believe).

Comment: @GauravMantri, yes. Stored Proc is working ok.

Comment: Have you tried logging the `response` value? What do you see there?

Comment: @GauravMantri, I didn't reach to that point. I am getting error when calling client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync.

Comment: The request is sent from client.  The stored procedure is on the server. Which means the request is good.  You should be getting a 200 OK status in the response from server to client.  We need to know the status of the response and what is contained in the body of the response.  Is stored procedure working or not working in server?  So said both.

Comment: Please don't create a new DocumentClient for every execution (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections?tabs=csharp#static-clients), you can use the DocumentClient from the binding, change this line `ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDbConnectionString")]DocumentClient client,`

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta, thanks for the info. I will use the DocumentClient from the binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is with the following line of code:

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("/id") };
```

You actually need to specify the value of the partition key here and not the attribute name.

Please try changing it to something like:

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("partition-key-value") };// Replace "partition-key-value" with actual value
```

Comment: I tried changing it with the partition-key-value but I still got the same error.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the complete error message.

Comment: The error message clearly indicates that the type of data returned by the Stored Procedure is not a string. I would recommend changing the stored procedure and return string data. Do something like `JSON.stringify(response)` and return that value.

Comment: Yeah, your right. I solve it by creating an object and use it  in ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync.  Thank you for helping me figuring out my issue

public class CosmosResponse
{
    public int Deleted { get; set; }
    public bool Continuation { get; set; }
}